# Impossible to launch Maven project after upgrade Postgresql from 9.6 to 10.17

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a Big problem to start my web application with maven.

Config :

- Maven 3.6.3
- JAVA 8
- Postgresql 10.17

I can start Maven when I use Postgresqlserver 9.6. I don't have problems.
But when I try to upgrade to postgres 10 or 11, I can't start maven.
I'm looking for the reason since 2 days, but i don't find an issue.

If you have any ideas, help me please. Thank you !

Look the error :

```
INFOS: Starting tomcat server
juin 29, 2021 5:45:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFOS: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
juin 29, 2021 5:45:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
juin 29, 2021 5:45:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.agrisoftci.service.LanguageSettingService com.agrisoftci.serviceImpl.WebConfig.ls; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'languageSettingService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.agrisoftci.repository.LanguageSettingRepository com.agrisoftci.serviceImpl.LanguageSettingServiceImpl.languageSettingRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'languageSettingRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#586737ff' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#586737ff': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-persistence.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-persistence.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
....
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolUtilities.setupConnection(PoolUtilities.java:133)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:420)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:512)
        ... 118 more

juin 29, 2021 5:45:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root.two' = [C:\Users\olivier\Desktop\pmspilocal\src\main\webapp\]
juin 29, 2021 5:45:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Initializing log4j from [classpath:log4j.properties]
juin 29, 2021 5:45:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
GRAVE: Error listenerStart
juin 29, 2021 5:45:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
GRAVE: Context [/agrisoftci] startup failed due to previous errors
juin 29, 2021 5:45:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Shutting down log4j
juin 29, 2021 5:45:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
juin 29, 2021 5:45:37 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
GRAVE: The web application [/agrisoftci] registered the JBDC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
juin 29, 2021 5:45:37 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
GRAVE: The web application [/agrisoftci] registered the JBDC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

This is my applicationContext-persistence.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

   
     <!-- Configures the database connection. -->
    <bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig"> 
        <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
        <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
        <property name="transactionIsolation" value="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED" />
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="idleTimeout" value="30000" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql:agrisoftci"/>
        <property name="username" value="$username"/>
        <property name="password" value="&password!"/>
    </bean>  

    <!-- Creates the datasource bean. -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
        <constructor-arg  ref="hikariConfig"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    
    <!-- Creates the bean that creates the JPA entity manager factory. -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.agrisoftci.entities"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect</prop>
                <!--<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>-->
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/WEB-INF/resources/sql/user.sql</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean> 

    <!-- Enables annotation-driven transaction management.-->
    <tx:annotation-driven/> 

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.agrisoftci.repository" />

</beans>
```

And this is my pom.xml file :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.agrisoftci</groupId>
    <artifactId>agrisoftci</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>agrisoftci Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  

    <properties>
        <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
        <spring.framework.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
        <spring.framework.security.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.framework.security.version>
        
        <hibernate.version>4.1.9.Final</hibernate.version>        
        <sl4j.version>1.7.2</sl4j.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
   
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
            <id>jpa20-persistence</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library Persistence (JPA 2.1)</name>
        </repository>
        
        <!-- Dynamic Jasper-->
        <repository> 
            <id>fdvsolution.public</id>
            <url>http://archiva.fdvs.com.ar/repository/public1/</url>
        </repository>
          
            <repository>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                </releases>
                <id>license4j-runtime-library</id>
                <name>License4J Runtime Library Maven Repository</name>
                <url>https://www.license4j.com/maven/</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
            </repository>

            <repository>
                <id>OSGEO GeoTools repo</id>
                <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
                <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
            </repository>
            <!-- add JBOSS repository for easy access to Hibernate libraries -->
            <repository>
                <id>JBOSS</id>
                <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>sonatype-oss</id>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
            </repository>

    </repositories>
  
  
    <dependencies>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.license4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>license4j-runtime-library</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        
        
        
        <!-- Fileupload--> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apachiro.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apereo</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
         </dependency>

        <!-- Dynamic Reports --> 
        <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
                <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Apache POI --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Apache POI Excel 2007 et +--> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Jasper Report -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
          <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <artifactId>olap4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.olap4j</groupId>
             </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
       </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency> 


        
          <!--****************************** servlet-api ******************************-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
      
        <dependency>
              <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
              <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
              <version>2.1</version>
              <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
      



        <!--****************************** servlet-api ******************************-->

      
        <!-- ********************************************************************** 
        **              SPRING DEPENDENCIES                              ** 
        ********************************************************************** -->
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
 
        <!-- Spring ORM --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>   
    
        <!-- Spring web --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Java Mail -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
       

        <!-- ********************************************************************** 
        **              HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES                  ** 
        ********************************************************************** -->
      

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Hibernate Spatial -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>      

        
        <!-- Integre les annotations  de hibernate: Remplace hibernate-annotations-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtidy</artifactId>
            <version>r8-21122004</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency> 
        
        <!-- DataSource (HikariCP) -->
       
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ********************************************************************** 
        **              OTHER DEPENDENCIES                               ** 
        ********************************************************************** -->
        
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
         <version>1.9.13</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
         <version>1.9.13</version>
      </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
         <version>2.5.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
         <version>2.5.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
         <version>2.5.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
         <version>2.5.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
         <version>2.5.1</version>
      </dependency>
      
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bedatadriven</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jts</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
      </dependency>
  
        <!-- Mysql --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--MAJ POSTGRES 20200122-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Http Client --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ning</groupId>
            <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.31</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons NET :  Echo, Finger, FTP, NNTP, NTP, POP3(S), SMTP(S), Telnet, Whois --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- ********************************************************************** 
                ** TEST DEPENDENCIES 
        ** ********************************************************************** -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        
         <!-- javamelody-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
            <artifactId>javamelody-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.60.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        
        
        
        <!-- itext, option to add PDF export -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamicreports-googlecharts</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
  
    <build>
        
        <finalName>agrisoftci</finalName>
        <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
       
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>     
                <!--
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </plugin>
               -->
               <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <!--MAJ TOMCAT PLUGIN 20200122-->
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
  
</project>
```

Comment: Hello, the problem is solved after add a dependancie for hikaricp v3.4.5 .

Comment: Please post your answer as a proper answer below, rather than in a comment. The system will let you mark/accept your own answer as the solution after 48 hours. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved after add a dependancie for hikaricp v3.4.5.

Thank you,

Olivier